# WCF - common data structures between server and client

Tags: wcf

I've looked around - can't find the answer to this, even in lots of sample code.

I'm trying to compile a WCF Service Application that uses [datacontract] classes as parameters on the interface members, which are from a global C# class library... This is on the server side. When I import the service reference into the client, it's re-namespace-based the global class library classes, and generated a bunch of serialization code!

I cannot add a reference to the global class library in the client project and use the classes freely. this seems clunky. I've checked the button when importing the service reference "reuse types", but I don't know what that does, but it's not the right thing.

During the import of the service library, it allows me to specify the namespace for the about-to-be-generated proxy classes. I'm pretty sure this isn't supposed to be the same namespace as the classes used on the server side!

example:

GLOBAL CLASS LIBRARY

namespace SquallGlobal

[datacontract] class ProcessStartInfo{ }

WCF SERVICE

namespace Squall

[servicecontract] interface IJob{

```
[OperationContract] StartJob( SquallGlobal.ProcessStartInfo psi );
```

}

END USER PROJECT

WCF Service imported under namespace 'Squall_Imported'

using SquallGlobal;

if I want to call proxy.StartJob( ), I need to pass in a Squall_Imported.ProcessStartInfo, not SquallGlobal.ProcessStartInfo!

Thus, the final question: How do I keep the proxy-generation code from re-basing the namespace on global classes used in interface methods?

Comment: One possible way would be to keep the client side code in a way so that it has access to both the global lib & the service, and use channel factory.

Comment: that wasn't the most detailed reply. it basically told me nothing.